# Another app is currently holding the yum lock; waiting for it to exit…

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, yum

I am working on ubuntu system and new in node.js, yum echo system.
ERROR : yum locked in my local system (ubuntu).

How can i solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution =>

1. sudo ps -ef| grep yum  // you will process id (p-id)
2. sudo kill -9 p-id

Comment: **Absolutely do not use `kill -9`** unless you have first exhausted all other options.